# connect react native with couchbase

Tags: react-native, couchbase

I am trying to create an app using react native app with the Couchbase mobile. I am new to react native and I couldn't find a better way to connect react native with Couchbase mobile. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried this: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/react-native-couchbase-lite

Answer (score 1):

You can use a couchbase module, a quick search showed that this module might be what you are looking for:
[react-native-couchbase](https://github.com/Upinion/react-native-couchbase-lite/blob/master/README.md)